# Blazor WASM MudBlazor UI Autocomplete large data set/virtualization

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

I have a Blazor WASM project that I'm trying to get a MudBlazor Autocomplete component to work with a very large data set. The api endpoint can return up to 10,000 results, so I do not want to load all the results in the OnInitializedAsync() method.
I want to use the MudBlazor Autocomplete SearchFunc to go out to the api and return a list, then filter the results.

Program.cs

```
var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");

builder.Services.AddMudServices();
builder.Services.AddScoped<CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
//TEST CONFIGURATION
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("ServerAPI",
      client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7083"))
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>()
  .CreateClient("ServerAPI"));

await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

AppPage.razor

```
public ProductMaster selectedProduct { get; set; } = new ProductMaster();

<MudAutocomplete 
            T="ProductMaster" 
            Label="Product" 
            @bind-Value="selectedProduct" 
            SearchFunc="@ProductSearch1"
            ToStringFunc="@(e => e == null ? "EMPTY" : $"{e.ProdDesc} {e.ProdCode}")"
            Variant="Variant.Outlined" 
            ShowProgressIndicator="true"
            ProgressIndicatorColor="Color.Default" /> 

private async Task<IEnumerable<ProductMaster>> ProductSearch1(string value)
        {
            var productList = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<IList<ProductMaster>>($"/api/Orders/GetProducts/?companyNumber={Order.Company}&prodDesc={value}");

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                return productList;

            return productList.Where(x => x.ProdDesc.Contains(value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
        }
```

The issue is, within the ProductSearch1 method, the http request never goes out. I cannot figure out why it won't execute. If I load all the results from the api on the **protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()** method, then filter the results as the user types it works fine. However, that won't work in my case, the data set is way too large.

Any thoughts on this?

Thanks

Comment: Firstly, why going through an HTTP request instead of using a service? It would be simpler and save you some network time, performance... Secondly, why not include the filter by `value` directly on the API in order to avoid sending data that you already know for sure you wouldn't need?

Comment: Are you saying have a separate class that when instantiated it does all the Http requests to populate a model and pass it to the razor.cs class? Also, if you look at the URI string, it includes a prodDesc. From there the Api uses a sql like statement to filter more appropriate results.

Comment: Since you were using a relative path, I guessed the API you are calling is hosted in the same server, is it? If yes, you can use a service to make the DB calls instead of calling the API on the same server. I indeed didn't realize you were already sending the `value`, however why are you filtering the list again ?

Comment: It's making a call to a remote server for the JSON. The URI is set in the program.cs file and is persisted throughout the application. We are filtering the list because the table has tens of thousands of records. It's pretty inefficient to load the whole data set. the &prodDesc='x' parameter in the HTTP Get is designed to return a subset of records. Regardless to that, the private async Task<IEnumerable<ProductMaster>> ProductSearch1(string value) method WILL NOT execute the Http request and I cannot understand why.

Comment: I meant why are you filtering the list twice? Where do you initialize `Http`, you should probably use an httpclient factory. Are you positive that `ProductSearch1` is executed? Lastly SignalR has a limited size for one message, if the data sent by your api exceeds it, I believe it returns nothing. There are several SO question about this SignalR matter.

Comment: I updated the code to show the dependency injection for the IHttpClientFactory. I actually mislabeled this project as Blazor Server when it actually is Web Assembly. I updated the question appropriately.  I wonder if the http requests won't go out out because of the scope defined in the dependency injection. What do you think?

Comment: If it comes from your HttpClient configuration, you may try to create an HttpClient directly in `ProductSearch1` and see what happens.

Comment: That's not a bad idea, I will give that a shot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by changing the dependency injection from Scoped to Singleton for the IHttpClientFactory:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>()
  .CreateClient("ServerAPI"));
```

to

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>()
  .CreateClient("ServerAPI"));
```